# How to create custom transaction ID php

Tags: javascript, php

Since I'm new in Web Development I've created an online Reservation system and I have a Transaction Id where the customer can cancel their reservation. I've already create a Transaction Id in a random characters and letters But I want to create custom Id
example: **2014-09-000010-PM** but I don't know what to search in google for any tutorials. Thanks for the help.
Btw here's my code for random characters and letters.

```
function createRandomPassword() {
                $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";
                srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
                $i = 0;
                $pass = '' ;
                while ($i <= 7) {
                    $num = rand() % 33;
                    $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
                    $pass = $pass . $tmp;
                    $i++;
                }
                return $pass;
            }
            $confirmation = createRandomPassword();
?>
```

Comment: A datetime is not a suitable ID.

Comment: So 2014 is for the year and 09 is for the month, I guess. How do you formulate the logic for 000010-PM?

Comment: Further to Sippy's comment... If an attacker can predict (_i.e._ guess) your transaction IDs, the attacker can do things like cancel or change others' reservations.  You should use a transaction ID that cannot be predicted.  Random sequences _may_ be good enough if you don't do things like use the time for the random number seed.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS it's just an example it could be 00001-PM. PM is for the name of the company

Comment: You can get the AUTO_INCREMENT value of a column from the table where you store the Transaction ID and append to it. This is just an idea.

Comment: And as others mentioned here, your Transaction ID must be un-predictable to eliminate the risk of un-authorized access or privacy issues. So one may try with 2014-09-000009-PM, 2014-09-000011-PM, 2014-09-000012-PM and so on.

Comment: Very well said @ViswalingaSuryaS or maybe I should stay random characters and letters for Transaction ID. what do you think? It is my professor suggest to create a custom Transaction ID

Comment: Just generate a 10 - 15 length characters which contains A-Z a-z 0-9 and check the generated text in the database table, whether it is already existing or not. So you get a 100% unique, unpredictable Transaction ID. It is really uncommon that you get identical transaction ID more than one time. But added security you check the same in your database for collisions.

Comment: Is it possible if it is example: 2014-09-a33dhty-PM the **a33dhty** would be the random characters and letters. do you think it will be unpredictable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the date function, as described in another answer, if you want a portion of the ID to be human-readable.  However, as I said in the comments, if an attacker can predict (*i.e.* guess) your transaction IDs, the attacker can do things like cancel or change others' reservations. You should use a transaction ID that cannot be predicted.  So, a date-based ID all by itself is dangerous.  You need the ID, or a portion of it, to be truly random.

The srand() function doesn't necessarily do that.  Its job is to generate a series of numbers that satisfy statistical tests for randomness, not unpredictability.  However, PHP does have a method for generating random numbers that are (probably) cryptographically secure.  Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Format it how you'd like with the date, and if you want to add in a random portion, or anything else, append to the string with something like variable += ' whatever ';

Also be sure your id is secure and unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage existing code. For example, [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s are unique, a version 1 UUID contains a timestamp, and the node can be used to add randomness (or a hash of information only you can retrieve.) It is also *very* commonly re-implemented, so you can find many tutorials. Remember you will need to be able to create the uuid, **and** be able to extract the information from the string representation later.

Or you could use [Rhumsaa\Uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) package (or any similarly complete library) to do all the work of initializing, translating the uuid and focus on what your code really needs to do.

```
use Rhumsaa\Uuid

// Uuid casts itself as a string whenever used as a string
$myTransactionId = Uuid::uuid1( $myHexNodeString, time() );

$uuidObject = Uuid::fromString( 'e886e43a-30b5-11e4-8751-7f0000014a23' );
// Creates a PHP DateTime object
// @see http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
$timestamp = $uuid->getDateTime();  
    // 2014-08-31T02:24:18+00:00
$myRetrievedHexNodeString = $uuid->getNodeHex()
    // 7f0000014a23
```